# Detect mouse leaving window with processing

Tags: mouseevent, processing

I have a program I am writing in processing and I need to be able to detect when the mouse has left the window/canvas. However, as far as I can tell, processing does not have anything similar to the mouseOut event. Is there any way to accomplish this using a callback or event or something of that nature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using knowledge of the window position plus its borders you could also calculate if pointer is inside frame or not. So then you can call your function.

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;

java.awt.Insets insets;
Point mouse, win;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
  frame.pack();
  smooth();
}

void draw() {
  setFrame();
  if(insideFrame()) {
    background(95);
  } 
  else {
   background(0); 
  }  
}

//set position of frame
void setFrame() 
{  
  mouse = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
  win = frame.getLocation();

  if(!frame.isUndecorated()){
    //add borders of window
    insets = frame.getInsets();
    win.x += insets.left;
    win.y += insets.top;
  }
}

boolean insideFrame() {
  boolean in = false;
  if(mouse.x-win.x >= 0 && width >= mouse.x-win.x)
    if(mouse.y-win.y >= 0 && height >= mouse.y-win.y)
      in = true;

  return in;
}
```

Comment: +1. I like this better than mine, I wanted to do something but didn't think mouseX and mouseY would be updated, and also didn't consider using the underlying java.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Java's `MouseAdapter` class. Example code:

```
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

void setup(){
  frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
      print("notify");
    }
  });
}
void draw(){}
```